# Como manter menu no topo (css)

Tags: jquery, css, blogger

Olá eu tenho um blogger gostaria de saber Como manter o menu no blogue no topo?

Comment: Como está o código? Não tem como responder assim, sem ver nada. Edite a pergunta e adicione o código do seu menu.

Comment: Não crie múltiplas perguntas para a mesma dúvida. Edite a [pergunta anterior](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/119008/menu-fixo-no-topo-de-blog-do-blogger) acrescentando mais detalhes e ela será reaberta.

Answer (score 1):

```
.top { 
  position: fixed; 
}
```

Só isso ;)